# Code snippets for JavaScript do nothing in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I tried to use code snippet for `for` loop. It should work like this:

1. Type `for`:
2. Suggestions should pop out: 
      [image: image description]
3. Click `for` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
4. Template should appear

What happens:
[image: image description] (that means nothing)

I tried other snippets, it was the same. I tried to use their "Report a problem" feature and I strongly advise anyone not to do the same mistake. I just lost text I wrote.

Is this a mistake in configuration? What should I fix?

Comment: Do you have a question, or just a bug report?

Comment: My question is why does it happen and how to fix it. This is a **major** feature and therefore this is not a bug report, this happens because some configuration mistake. Also, it's completely valid to ask for workarounds over bugs.

Comment: Notwithstanding the fact that it's not clear to me why you don't consider a major feature not working as you expected to be a bug, it may be difficult for people to diagnose an issue in configuration you haven't actually shown.